# Python-requests not clearing memory when downloading with sessions

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an application where I use requests to download .mp3 files from a server.

The code looks like this:

```
self.client = requests.session(headers={'User-Agent': self.useragent})

def download(self, url, name):
    request = self.client.get(url)

    with open(name, "wb") as code:
        code.write(request.content)

    print "done"
```

The problem is that when the download is finished, python does not clear the memory, so everytime I download an mp3, the memory usage of the application raises by the size of the mp3. The memory does not get cleared again, leading to my app using a lot of memory.

I assume this has to do with how I save the file, or how requests.session works.

Any suggestions.

Edit:
Here is the code:
https://github.com/Simon1988/VK-Downloader

The relevant part is in lib/vklib.py

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code? It's impossible to figure out where the garbage collector (might be) failing without it.

Comment: @frb - I have edited my post to include the entire codebase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try streaming the content in chunks:

```
def download(self, url, name):
    request = self.client.get(url, stream=True)  # `prefetch=False` for older
                                                 # versions of requests
    with open(name, "wb") as code:
        for chunk in request.iter_content(1024):
            if not chunk:
                break

            code.write(chunk)
```

Comment: The `del` is unlikely to have much effect. The request will be deleted at the end of the scope (CPython) or a few seconds later/after there's enough memory pressure (most other implementations).

Comment: Tried using del, did nothing.
Using your other suggestion, I get:
    RuntimeError: The content for this response was already consumed

Comment: @scandinavian_: Did you put `stream=True` or `prefetch=False` in your `.get()` function?

Comment: @scandinavian_: Also, did you use exactly this code, or did you combine this code with your original, and end up checking `content` before using `iter_content`?

Comment: It looks like this: request = self.client.get(url, prefetch=True). 

Using stream=True I get: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'stream'

Comment: @Blender: You mean `prefetch=False` for older versions, not True, right? (I don't actually remember, but it seems to make more sense that way…)

Comment: @abarnert - It works with prefetch=False - Everything seems to be working now. I downloaded 10 * 5 mb Mp3's and memory usage stayed at 12 mb. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's an actual problem here, beyond you not understanding how memory allocation works.

When Python needs more memory, it asks the OS for more. When it's done with that memory, it generally does not return it to the OS; instead, it holds onto it for later objects.

So, when you open the first 10MB mp3, your memory use goes from, say, 3MB to 13MB. Then you free up that memory, but you're still at 13MB. Then you open a second 10MB mp3, but it reuses the same memory, so you're still at 13MB. And so on.

In your code, you're creating a thread for each download. If you have 5 threads at a time, all using 10MB, obviously that means you're using 50MB. And that 50MB won't be released. But if you wait for them to finish, then do another 5 downloads, it'll reuse the same 50MB again.

Since your code doesn't limit the number of threads in any way, there's nothing (short of CPU speed and context-switching costs) to stop you from kicking off hundreds of threads, each using 10MB, meaning gigabytes of RAM. But just switching to a thread pool, or not letting the user kick off more downloads if too many are gong on, etc., will solve that.

So, usually, this is not a problem. But if it is, there are two ways around it:

1. Create a child process (e.g., via the `multiprocessing` module) to do the memory-hogging work. On any modern OS, when a process goes away, its memory is reclaimed. The problem here is that allocating and releasing 10MB over and over again is actually going to slow your system down, not speed it up—and the cost of process startup (especially on Windows) will make it even worse. So, you'll probably want a much larger batch of jobs to spin off to a c child process.
2. Don't read the whole thing into memory at once; use a streaming API instead of a whole-file API. With `requests`, this means setting `stream=True` in the initial request, and then usually using `r.raw.read(8192)`, `r.iter_content()`, or `r.iter_lines()` in a loop instead of accessing `r.content`.

Comment: "Then you open a second 10MB mp3, but it reuses the same memory, so you're still at 13MB. And so on."

The problem is that it does not reuse the memory. Say I download 10, 5 mb MP3 files, my python app is using 50 mb + standard memory usage.

Comment: @scandinavian_: Ah… Looking at your code, you're doing a bunch of downloads in parallel using threads. If you've got 5 requests going at the same time, each using 10MB, of course that will use 50MB!

Comment: @abernet - I tested without the gui, using no threads. But fetching in chunks seem to keep the memory usage down.

Comment: @scandinavian_: Yes, if you're only reading a few K at a time, even if you do hundreds of them in parallel, that's only going to take 1MB or so. (You still probably don't actually want to do hundreds of them in parallel, for other reasons… but that's another story.)

Comment: The app is for downloading Mp3's from the Russian facebook clone vk.com (they don't give a shit about copyright in Russia it seems.). Are you talking about chunksize, or just that I shouldn't allow downloading multiple files at once? What would be the smartest way to do it? @abarnert

Comment: @scandinavian_: I would use a thread pool with a queue, so you only download, say, 4 files at a time. (A web browser typically uses a rule like "only 8 total files at a time, only 2 on the same server". You can probably push it farther than that, but if the user tries to download hundreds of tracks, don't try to do them all at the same time.)

Comment: @scandinavian_: Also, most of the countries in Scandinavia do give a shit about copyright (at least so long as the US government and/or RIAA is paying the government a lot of money to care and issuing scary threats if the bribes don't work), so you might want to be careful.

Comment: I will look into that @abarnert, it's my first GUI project (one of the first serious python projects too), so I'm still getting used the pyqt syntax. Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.
Also, just to be sure, is there a performance difference with what chunk size you choose?

Comment: Regarding copyright, as long as I don't host anything (And it doesn't get too popular), I'm reasonably safe :)

Comment: @scandinavian_: There _is_ a performance difference, but it's hard to predict (it's much easier to try different values and time the results), and usually not big enough to matter. Just sticking to the `iter` methods (which have their own internal buffer) or using the standard 8192 or 4096 with `raw.read` is almost always fine.