# Understanding memory consumption increase in python using Requests HTTP library

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory, memory-management, python-requests

I am using python v2.7 and [Requests HTTP library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#). I am using windows 7 OS.

I have failed to understand why the following code consumes more and more memory upon execution? I have observed the memory consumption using task manager. It would be great if some one can point out what could be the possible reason and how to avoid it? Also it would be great if some one can test this on his/her system and confirm that it is not only me or my system who is facing this problem. :) Although the memory consumption increases with a small amount, I think at some point my app will surely crash when there is no more free memory left.

**Code**:

```
import requests
def getName():
    url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/users/2382792/pss'
    r = requests.get(url)
    print r

while True:
    getName()
```

The reason for this simple question is provided in detail below. Also I have a similar problem with [urllib2 module too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22684271/regarding-memory-consumption-in-python-with-urllib2-module) So I thought of using Requests HTTP library. But the same problem regarding the memory consumption persists.

**Real world scenario**: My real world app is built with python and wxPython. The wxPython code doesn't causes this problem. The python code which is connecting to the URLs to fetch some values from the server is causing the problems. To keep the values updated the values are fetched after every 2 seconds. These fetched values are then displayed on the GUI. The code shown above is the a sample of my original code. More over in above code sample there is only one instance of connecting to an URL. *`In my real world app I have 9-10 threads those are doing this fetching stuff by connecting to different URLs! Which means in this case the memory consumption increases more rapidly as compared to the above sample code.`* I hope now it is more clear how severe this problem is. Also, just for the clarification I am not scrapping any website.

**Comparison**: Why the following code doesn't have the same problem as the code above:

```
import random
def getValue():
    value = random.randrange(0,11)
    print value
while True:
    getValue()
```

**Update:** I tested the code snippet for half an hour. I have finally concluded that the memory consumption increases in the beginning and later it gets in a state where it decreases as well as increases. Finally the memory consumption will remain in a range.
Here is a graph created from [processExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) on Windows 8 OS. The middle one is for the memory(Right click the image and click view to see it clearly):
[image: pexplorer]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: How does this post relate to your [previous question on the same subject](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22685507)?

Comment: As it stands, they are duplicates yes. Just simplify the first post and delete this one, or delete the other post and leave this one.

Comment: Ok then I'll remove the other one. :) Deleted

Comment: I think the memory is not re-allocated or released by Pythons memory allocation system. Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270053/python-requests-not-clearing-memory-when-downloading-with-sessions) helps or this [one](http://python.dzone.com/articles/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python)

Comment: The memory usage costs from 9.7MB -> 10.1MB in OSX Mavericks.

Comment: Here's what I found: for letting the loop run for 100 iterations, my memory usage increased for ~4.9 MB. For 500 iterations, it only went up by ~0.7 MB. I don't see any caching in requests library source code. Perhaps, server caching might be the culprit. Anyway, if you are trying to scrape a website, I suggest you to use scrapy - it's async and far more efficient..

Comment: @ShanValleru Thanks for the efforts! I hope increasing memory won't crash my application in a long run. More over I am not scraping a website. In my real world app I am simply connecting to different URLs to fetch some values using threads.

Comment: can you confirm that memory consumption stops increasing after some time?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I usually waited for 6-10 minutes and it keeps increasing. I shall edit my question and put some more details regarding the amount of consumption and the time span

Comment: Can you print out memory consumption per second during that period, and plot it? It would help to know if it's linear, sublinear or superlinear.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the system isn't behaving the way it was designed to behave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the code snippet for half an hour. I have finally concluded that the memory consumption increases in the beginning and later it gets in a state where it decreases as well as increases. Finally the memory consumption will remain in a range. I believe this is how the system is supposed to work after reading the useful comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

I can only second some of the comments on your original post. I found http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection to be quite useful in case you want to gain better insight into the gc.