# How to free python program memory buildup over time, File I/O

Tags: python

I have a function that downloads and saves html pages. Over time, the memory is not being released and the program becomes slow. How can I force release this memory (or what is taking up this memory?

I think the problem may be with reading, writing the file. Although I call close(), could there be another issue?

The following code is inside a for loop (this is done 1000+ times)

```
openFile = None

try:
    #download the page
    pageText = getPageAsText(url)

    #write file to disk
    fileName = name
    openFile = open(os.path.expanduser('~')+STATIC_DIRECTORY+'/'+name, 'w')
    openFile.write(pageText)

except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()

finally:
    if openFile is not None:
        openFile.close()
```

Comment: Nothing about the code you've shown obviously builds up memory usage. The problem seems to lie elsewhere, perhaps in the surrounding code or in `getPageAsText`.

Comment: Can you plot a graph for the memory consumption and post it. Also, please provide the details regarding how much memory is being consumed? We can compare it with our system. Finally please have a look at this question too.  Maybe you can get some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687952/understanding-memory-consumption-increase-in-python-using-requests-http-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can  `del` to dereference not used variables. It gives a hint to garbage collector to collect the memory earlier. Without your entire code, we cannot see where the memory leak occurs.

I would also rewrite your code with `with`, so it handles close by itself.

```
 pageText = getPageAsText(url)
 with open(os.path.expanduser('~')+STATIC_DIRECTORY+'/'+name, 'w') as f:
      f.write(pageText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `gc` manually as [gc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html).
But your data is not released so it doesn't work properly.

add the code in the end of loop

```
pageText = None
fileName = None
openFile = None
```

Python gc will work automatically.

Comment: It should "work" anytime their values are changed. (It won't actually collect every time, but the abandonment of old values is what eventually activates the garbage collector.)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the problem may be elsewhere, but to force garbage collection:

```
import gc
gc.collect()    # force garbage collection
```