# Multiprocessing queue - Why does the memory consumption increase?

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The following script generates 100 random dictionaries of size 100000, feeds each (key, value) tuple into a queue, while one separate process reads from the queue:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

import numpy.random as nr


def get_random_dict(_dummy):
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in enumerate(nr.randint(pow(10, 9), pow(10, 10), pow(10, 5))))

def consumer(q):
    for (k, v) in iter(q.get, 'STOP'):
        pass

q = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
p.start()
for d in mp.Pool(1).imap_unordered(get_random_dict, xrange(100)):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        q.put((k, v))
q.put('STOP')
p.join()
```

I was expecting the memory usage to be constant because the consumer process pulls data from the queue as the main process feeds it. I verified that data doesn't accumulate in the queue.

However, I monitored the memory consumption and it keeps increasing as the script runs. If I replace `imap_unordered` by `for _ in xrange(100): d = get_random_dict()`, then the memory consumption is constant. What is the explanation?

Comment: Perhaps this can help you in some way http://stackoverflow.com/q/22687952/2382792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pool.imap` is not literally identical to `imap`. It is the same in that it can be used like `imap` and that it returns an iterator. However, the implementation is entirely different. The backing pool will be working as hard as it can to complete all the jobs given to it as quickly as possible, regardless how how quickly the iterator is being consumed. If you only wanted a job to be processed when requested then there would be no point in using `multiprocessing`. Might as well just use `itertools.imap` and be done with it.

The reason that your memory consumption is increasing is therefore because the pool is creating dictionaries faster than your consumer process is consuming them. This will be because the way a pool retrieves results from a worker process is uni-directional (one process writes and process reads), and so no explicit synchronisation mechanism is needed. Whereas, a `Queue` is bidirectional -- both processes can read and write to the queue. This means there needs to be explicit synchronisation between processes using a queue to make sure they aren't competing to add the next item to a queue or remove an item from the queue (thus leaving the queue in an inconsistent state).

Comment: Very clear explanation! I've written a module to limit the number of concurrent values which will help in this cases: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bounded-iterator/

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main problem is using `multiprocessing.Pool` to collect the dictionaries created in one process (`Pool` process), and then put them in the queue in main process. I think (I may be wrong) that `Pool` creates some queues of its own, and those are probably the ones in which the data accumulates.

You can see that clearly if you put some debugging prints like this:

```
...
def get_random_dict(_dummy):
    print 'generating dict'
    ...
...
for d in mp.Pool(1).imap_unordered(get_random_dict, xrange(100)):
    print 'next d'
    ...
```

You'll then see something like this:

```
generating dict
generating dict
next d
generating dict
generating dict
generating dict
generating dict
generating dict
next d
...
```

Which clearly shows you have those generated `dict`s accumulated somewhere
(probably in the inner tubing of `Pool`).

I think that much better solution would be to put the data from the
`get_random_dict` directly to the queue and abandon using `*map` functions
from `Pool`.